# Api-platform 2.7 - Can't use custom state provider to customize POST response

Tags: php, symfony, dto, api-platform.com

I'm using api-platform 2.7 to make an API. I like to control what the requests can accept and what the response send back so I use DTO. I try to customize what a POST request will return. I only want to show specific data from my `User` entity, so I've made an `UserPostOutput` DTO and an `UserPostOutputProvider`, but the `UserPostOutputProvider` is never reached (I put breakpoints and I use xDebug) and the response keep showing me all datas from my `User` entity instead of the `UserPostOutput` DTO.

This is my `UserPostOutput` DTO :

```
<?php

namespace App\DTO\User;

class UserPostOutput
{
    public int $id;

    public string $email;
}
```

This is my `User` entity (I cut all the getters and setters) :

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use App\DataTransformer\User\UserPostInputProcessor;
use App\DataTransformer\User\UserPostOutputProvider;
use App\DTO\User\UserPostInput;
use App\DTO\User\UserPostOutput;
use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use DateTimeImmutable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

#[Post(
    input: UserPostInput::class,
    output: UserPostOutput::class,
    provider: UserPostOutputProvider::class,
    processor: UserPostInputProcessor::class,
)]
#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: UserRepository::class)]
class User implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 180, unique: true)]
    private ?string $email = null;

    #[ORM\Column]
    private array $roles = [];

    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?string $password = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $firstName = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    private ?string $lastName = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255)]
    private ?string $userName = null;
```

And this is my `UserPostOutputProvider` :

```
<?php

namespace App\DataTransformer\User;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Operation;
use ApiPlatform\State\ProviderInterface;
use App\DTO\User\UserPostOutput;

class UserPostOutputProvider implements ProviderInterface
{
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): UserPostOutput
    {
        $userPostOutput = new UserPostOutput();
        $userPostOutput->email = $uriVariables['email'];
        $userPostOutput->id = $uriVariables['id'];

        return $userPostOutput;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is autowiring enabled?

Comment: @EvgenyRuban yes it's enabled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was on the same track as you but after some more try an error i now think this is not how its ment to be.
I think only Get requests use the provider and Post,Put,Delete use the processor.

If you want to return the UserPostOutput from your Post you can return it from the processor.

I hope this helps, the documentation on Dtos from Apiplatform is a bit short, so I am also still figuring out things.

Comment: Okay thank you I think too that it's not ment to be used like this. I'll try to use the processor as you suggest.

Comment: `put` uses providers too.